# jqm mouse events simulation for testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQueryMobile for a web-app. For app-testing I simulate the click-events.

For example, a button-click is simulated like this:

```
<button id="myButton">button</button>

$('#myButton').click();
```

Now I have list-items I can drag aside to reveal a menu below them. To drag the list-item aside I use the jqm-vmousemove event:

```
list.find('#myItem').on('vmousemove'), function(event){
    ...
    distance = e.pageX       
}
```

To simulate this I need a function like this:

```
$('#myItem').vmousemove({page.Y=0px, page.X=10px});
$('#myItem').vmousemove({page.Y=0px, page.X=20px});
```

To simulate a drag event of 10px.

But this doesn't work. Any ideas how to simulate the vmousemove event of jQueryMobile?

Comment: quotes required in 0px and so on... and also not pageX and pageY ??

Comment: Oh, this hast just been an example of how it could look like. I have no idea what parameters I have to set to the vmousemove(..)-function. I couldn't find any hints in the jqm-api about the parameter and a function-call.

Answer (score 0):

There's a test tool you can use but you will need to be careful.

jQuery UI has a tool for unit testing and you can use it with **jQuery Mobile**. Just be careful when including **jQuery UI** with **jQuery Mobile**, I can't remember correctly, but from my memory **jQuery UI** must be initialized before **jQuery Mobile** (if it's not working then go other way).

You can find plugin here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/jquery.simulate.js

Example is here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/unit/draggable/draggable_core.js

Basically all you need to do is:

```
element.simulate( "drag", {
    dx: 1,
    dy: 1
});
```

Of course you will need to make a draggable element abd that should not be a problem, **jQuery UI** works just find with **jQuery Mobile**.... usually ;)